# Paytm library 2.1 integration with iOS Linker Error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, paytm

Following linker error with duplicate symbol showing while integrating Paytm library for iOS.
Here is few line of error :

> duplicate symbol _OBJCIVAR$_Reachability.reachabilityRef in :
>   Library/Paytm/libPaymentsSDK.a(Reachability.o) ld: 9 duplicate symbols
>   for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please help me out to fix this issue .

*Note 1 - When i wrote to discussion forum i got reply :

**"issue is your Reachability class has same name as of paytm Reachability class
so simply solution is to change the name of your Reachability class
"**

but the problem is to change the reachability class name in the entire project is not a feasible solution .

*Note 2 :-

**Using Xcode7.2 along with Mac OSX 10.11.2 (Objective C - Language )**

*Note 3 :-

in Paytm library there is a header file having name : **PaymentsSDK.h** which have

```
//Reusable Class Redefines to avoid name clashes
//#define Reachability PGReachability
```

when i uncomment above line .. still it is giving error ??

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I am Also using Paytm library 2.1 integration But I am not getting ur Problem..

Comment: have u used Reachability class in your project !

Comment: rename your Reachability class and try.

Comment: Ya i am using Reachability class

Comment: any updates here, facing same issue? using  PGSDK_VERSION   @"2.7"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the latest version of the PG SDK library from Paytm. They have fixed the problem. Recently few merchants had reported that issue. So they have fixed it by renaming that class so that it does not clash with yours.

Comment: need to use Paytm library not PG SDK

Comment: well , the latest version m using is 2.1 from here i downloaded https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_iOS_App_Kit. Please suggest me  url to download the lastest one . version 2.1 is pushed 18 days ago . i guess .

Comment: I also tried to uncomment to //Reusable Class Redefines to avoid name clashes

#define Reachability    PGReachability  this in paytm lib .

Comment: If you are a registered merchant with Paytm payments then you should contact the Paytm contact point to get the latest SDK. The latest release is 2.7. I am not sure why they have posted the old version to github

Comment: well dint get sdk2.7 so used alternative way to solve this problem by simply following : Compile source - simply remove Reachability.m file . (Dint remove from the project only from compile source ) and it did the work . It may help others too.

Comment: could you please join this group http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15038/ios-developer-family

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Reachability Class .m file from your Project and Run. This will work.

Go to Project Settings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> Select Reachability.m -> Delete it.

This won't delete the file from the system, only from the compilation. The header will be used and the implementation won't be duplicated.

(Also You can remove the file from Paytm SDK thourgh terminal.)

Comment: It gives linnker error . i already tried this. one more thing can't delete the paytm sdk reachabilty file

Answer (score -1):

**SOLVED..!!!**

> I have deleted my own "**Reachability**" class and used
>   "**SCNetworkReachability**". And modified all my old reachability methods
>   with the new class.

https://cocoapods.org/pods/SCNetworkReachability